# SQLite does not give syntax error on mistyped data type

Tags: sqlite

I am new to sqlite3 but this seems strange for any dbms

I was trying to create the following table but mistyped decimal to dcimal

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE ac(
   ...> name char(4),
   ...> pay  dcimal(18,5)
   ...> );
```

However it allowed me to create the table.
To add to my surprise I tested the below `CREATE TABLE`

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE ac(
   ...> name r(4),
   ...> pay  l(18,5)
   ...> );
```

in both cases not only it allows me to create table but also allows me to insert and retrieve data from it.

```
sqlite> insert into ac values ('dbcd',18.2);
sqlite> select * from ac;
dbcd|18.2
```

Is there any way to enforce strict syntax checks, so that it error outs on these junk data types ?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

No.
SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so it does not care whether you are using `dcimal` or `fluffy bunnies` or no data type at all.